# Dynamically fetch Custom Labels in Apex class

Tags: metadata, customlabel

I need to dynamically fetch Custom Labels in Apex class, something like

Get All Labels where name like 'a%'

I see SOQL does not support querying Custom Labels and although I see Metadata API can be used to fetch values I have not been able to get hold of any method that helps do so. Is there a method like Metadata.Operations.retrieve that helps read Custom Metadata.

Comment: Can you describe the use case a little bit? What would you be doing with a list of custom labels that begin with the letter `a`?

Comment: You can use the Apex Metadata API wrapper in github - https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi